# How can this program crash after at the last line (return 0;)?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a program, divided in multiple files and with a lot of code containing arrays, pointers, structs and what not.

To come to the point: these are my last lines of my `main()` method;

```c
   ...
   printf("\nLast line!");
   return 0;
}
```

After I compiled this program without warnings, I executed it and in my console I get the text: `Last line!` in my CMD and after that the program crashes (doesn't respond).

I often use `printf()`'s to debug my code and determine the line in my code where the program crashes. In this case I cannot wrap my head around the fact that the program crashes **after** the last line of code.

My questions:

- Could `return 0;` in the main function cause a crash?
- Is it possible the program crashes due to undefined behaviour earlier in my program?

  - If so, how can I debug my code? (I'm using Windows 7)

Note: I know for sure there is only one `printf("\nLast line!");` in my code.

Comment: "_And is it possible the program crashes due to undefined behavior earlier in my program?_" -- **Yes**. Google "_segmentation fault in return statement_" and you'll find lots of results on this.

Comment: @CoolGuy ok, so now I have to find it :)

Comment: Alas: "compiled this program without warnings" only means your program does not contain syntactic errors. Logical errors, such as overwriting memory you don't own or dividing by zero, won't cause a compiler warning or error.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "after that the program crashes (doesn't respond)" ? Does it crash, or does it just "not respond" ? What do you mean by "doesn't respond"? What do you expect it to do when you return from main()?

Comment: OK, so you corrupted the stack and blew away the main() return address?

Comment: @MartinJames That sounds cool so lets say, yes I did :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *could `return 0;` in the `main()` function cause a crash?*

As for the statement alone, No, it won't cause a *crash*.

> *And is it possible the program crashes due to undefined behavior earlier in my program?*

Yes. Most likely so. You invoked [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) somewhere earlier in your code, and the result, as you know, is undefined.

> *If so, how can I debug my code?*

Try to run your program through a debugger and memory checker, like `gdb` on linux and valgrind. Also, ry to add breakpoint in your code in *tricky* areas and step through the debugger while checking the actual value against the expected value. Most likely, you'll be able to spot the error.

Answer (score 1):

Also stop using `printf();` try a good debugger like(`gdb`) it's much more simpler and more faster to debug C code